# Possible warped brakes?

Tags: brake-rotor

Im getting a vibration at anything over 70mph when applying the brakes heavily. I've taken a look at the brakes and there's no obvious discolouration which would suggest warping. The discs are of the floating type and are quite heavy duty. 355 x32 mm (13 x 1.2 inch) I haven't ever driven it hard enough to warp them I don't think.
Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like warped rotors to me. Are they aftermarket?

Comment: No standard. Covered 20k miles. The vibration is through the steering wheel rather than through the pedal like with warped brakes. Also with these brakes being 355 tall and 32mm thick god knows how you warp them!

Comment: So I just took the car on a private road and did a few hard stops from 160 to about 40 over and over then a few from 60 to 10. Vibration is still there but not as bad. I'm thinking it could be the pads following a slight lip on the sides as recently had caliper replaced on one side under warranty

Comment: Would this be a lip on the outside of the rotor that's outside of where the pads normally wear it down?

Comment: Yes the lip is on the outside about 1/2 to 1mm.

Comment: Id start by getting discs measured and machined to ruke that out. If it still occurs then if be looking at wheel alignment and play in steering and ball joints. I assume tyres are in good condition and inflated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not the ABS system juddering because of the heavy braking then it may be warped discs. There is no rhyme or reason why discs warp, I have had them warp badly after 10K miles with careful use then slowly get better but still vibrate.  The cheapest way to find out is to buy some cheap discs and see if the vibration goes away immediately. Cheaper than going to a brake specialist.

Comment: Theres no pulsing through the pedal. its not abs. TBF I've never felt the ABS kick in on this car the tyres and brakes are huge.

Comment: Unfortunately "cheap" brakes for this are about 700GBP. I think skimming them would be more cost effective.